# Windows 10 visual effects settings automatically restoring to defaults after some time under user type of account

Tags: windows, windows-10, default-settings

When I change [Windows 10 visual effects settings](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6377-change-visual-effects-settings-windows-10-a.html)  after some time they automatically restoring to default settings. I am working under user type of account (non administrator type).

**Question:** How to prevent such type of behavior?

Comment: Try to run `SystemPropertiesPerformance` (spelled as one word) from the Start menu or the Run box, and these settings may stick better.

Comment: @harrymc It worked. Thank you. If you want you can write answer and I will accept it, if no I will write it later. Also is there a way to access same menu from Control Panel?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it happens that Windows 10 visual effects settings don't stick.

Running `SystemPropertiesPerformance` (spelled as one word) from the Start menu
or from the Run box, may in such cases work better at making these settings stick.